# Can the process read the file? SetUID privilege collision

Tags: permissions, privileges, setuid

User A executes a `setuid` program owned by user B. the program wants to read a file in /etc/data, that is only readable by A and no one else. Can the program read the file?

And then I have another question, similar to the one above.

A process wants to read a file, the effective user id of the process is 3000 and the real user id is 4000. The file is readable for `userID=4000` but not for `userID=3000`, can the process read the file?

Comment: Homework questions?

Comment: Kind of, I have come up with a solution but I'm trying to see what someone more experienced has to say